# Why debug and test skips over a method returning IEnumerable<t> in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, ienumerable, xunit

Recently, I tried and failed so many times with xUnit test with the below code :

```
// testing target
IEnumerable<T> Foo(int n) 
{
    if(n==0) throw new AnException();

    foreach(var item in ..)
    {
        yield return item;
    {
    yield break;
}

// test Method

void action() => Foo(0) ;
Assert.Throw<AnException>(action);
```

So, I decided to debug Foo method by setting break points in VS and calling it in another sandbox project(console app), which just calls the method.

However, the control flow wouldn't enter into the method scope and just ended its execution.

So, I changed my code as below:

```
// test Method
void action ()
{
    foreach(var item in Foo(0) ) {}// literally empty code inside loop.
}
Assert.Throw<AnException>(action);
```

That change really works with debug and test as well.

Can you tell me what made that difference?

Answer (score 2):

That call to `Foo(0)` as in  `void action() => Foo(0);` is not consuming (read as: looping  over) the `IEnumerable`.
You can use one of the `Linq` methods to do so, e.g. [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any).

You'll need to include the `System.Linq` namespace.
The code then looks like below.

```
void action() => Foo(0).Any();
```

Comment: Thanks for comments but I would like to know about something under hood that makes foreach and .Any() from Linq work while just calling doesn't. Linq is easy and fancy but hiding so many things more than foreach.

Comment: @BigSquare That's in the 'consuming' part in my answer; just a call to a method that returns an `IEnumerable` doesn't go into its body. To do so, you need a loop, e.g. a `foreach` or a `ToList`, or `Any`. That's what e.g. an `Any` does; notice the `MoveNext` statement in the [`source code`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1288)

Comment: I understood you meant the essence lays on 'MoveNext'. I searched for it in MS Docs and found not much but it says 'foreach' was implemented to call 'MoveNext'. I think it continues to execute statements in 'Foo' method until it meets the first 'yield return'. is it?

Comment: Here's a link to the [technical implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield#technical-implementation) explaining the relation to `IEnumerable`, `MoveNext` and `yield`.

Comment: oh. that's awesome. Upvoted.